# Is it possible to get the user from a text in a Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, document

I've been searching for two days, but I can't find even a mention of what I want to do. In a Google Document, I want each user to type in a different color. Just like you see when you check the revisions. Maybe the easiest would be that every time the document is opened, the  font color changes according to which user it is, but this isn't waterproof. I don't know if any of you guys have tried something similar or could point me to some docs I've missed? I know it is possible to get the e-mail address of the active user, so my little plan to change the color when the document is opened could work, but you know...

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a rough idea on how you could implement this:

1. Create an onEdit function with the eventinfo argument.
2. The eventinfo argument contains two properties that we will use i.e range and user
3. Now that we have the user, we need to check if a font has been assigned to this user.
4. You could use script properties for this and if not found you need to assign a unique font color (I leave this logic to you).
5. Once the color has been pulled from the script properties you need to set the font on the range obect with the retrieved color

This should word do try and let us know.